# Obter resultado específico através de comparação entre array's através do for do Javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso de ajuda para imprimir um resultado através do código abaixo: 
*Resultado esperado:* `e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434 | 1 | 2020-04-01 - c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4 | 1 | 2020-04-02` 
*(erro) Resultado obtido:* `e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434 | 1 | 2020-04-01 - c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4 | 2 | 2020-04-01,2020-04-02`

```
$array_cods = "e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434|c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4";
$array_dias = "2020-01-15,2020-01-20,2020-01-22,2020-01-27,2020-01-29,2020-02-03,2020-02-05,2020-02-10,2020-02-12,2020-02-17,2020-02-19,2020-02-24,2020-02-26,2020-03-02,2020-03-04,2020-03-09,2020-03-11,2020-03-16,2020-03-18,2020-03-23,2020-03-25,2020-03-30,2020-04-01,2020-04-06,2020-04-08,2020-04-13,2020-04-15,2020-04-20|2020-04-02,2020-04-07,2020-04-08,2020-04-09,2020-04-14,2020-04-15,2020-04-16,2020-04-21";
$array_datas = "2020-04-01,2020-04-02"
```

```
var allcods = "<?php echo $array_cods; ?>";
var cods = allcods.split('|');

var alldias = "<?php echo $array_dias; ?>";
var diasa = alldias.split('|');
var diasb = String(alldias.split('|'));

var alldatas = "<?php echo $array_datas; ?>";
var datas = alldatas.split(',');

for(var i=0; i<cods.length; i++) { //--- Sempre será executado pela quantidade de cods
    executar();
}

function executar() {
    for(var i=0; i<cods.length; i++) {
        var dias = diasb.split(',');

        var arr = dias.some(dias => datas.includes(dias));
        var b = String(dias);
        var c = String(datas);
        var a = b.indexOf(parseInt(c));

        if (arr == true) {
            console.log(cods+" | "+datas.length+" | "+c);
            break;
        } else { 
            console.log(cods+" | Não");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**O cód. c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4 não pode obter 2, porque ele não tem a data 2020-04-01**

Vejam um exemplo do erro usando as datas 2020-04-01 a 2020-04-13

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**No cód. c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4 deveria ser 4**

Desculpe, o código tá cheio de testes e testes
**[Exemplo no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brendowsilas/a3vq79mb/25/)**

**O código abaixo tá muito mexido e cheio de testes, mas tá funcionando:**

```js
function calcDayAtes() { //----- Somar dias do Atestado
  //var idnClient = document.getElementById("idClient").value;
  var dtInicat = document.getElementById('dtinicat').value;
  var dtTerat = document.getElementById('dtterat').value;

  var resultados = "2020-01-15,2020-01-20,2020-01-22,2020-01-27,2020-01-29,2020-02-03,2020-02-05,2020-02-10,2020-02-12,2020-02-17,2020-02-19,2020-02-24,2020-02-26,2020-03-02,2020-03-04,2020-03-09,2020-03-11,2020-03-16,2020-03-18,2020-03-23,2020-03-25,2020-03-30,2020-04-01,2020-04-06,2020-04-08,2020-04-13,2020-04-15,2020-04-20|2020-04-02,2020-04-07,2020-04-08,2020-04-09,2020-04-14,2020-04-15,2020-04-16,2020-04-21";
  var results = resultados.split('|');

  var nwdtInicat = dtInicat.split('/').reverse().join('-');
  var nwdtTerat = dtTerat.split('/').reverse().join('-');

  var pinic = nwdtInicat.split("-");
  var iano = pinic[0];
  var imes = pinic[1] - 1;
  var idia = pinic[2];
  var newInicial = new Date(iano, imes, idia);

  var pterm = nwdtTerat.split("-");
  var tano = pterm[0];
  var tmes = pterm[1] - 1;
  var tdia = pterm[2];
  var newFinal = new Date(tano, tmes, tdia);

  var milissegundos_por_dia = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var data_inicial = new Date(newInicial.getTime() - 0 * milissegundos_por_dia);
  var data_final = new Date(newFinal.getTime() + 1 * milissegundos_por_dia);

  //alert(data_inicial);

  if ((dtInicat) && (dtTerat)) {

    //console.log(data_inicial);
    //console.log(data_final);

    //if (nwdtInicat > nwdtTerat) { msgErro("default|Conflito nas datas! <br> A data inicial não pode ser maior que a data final!|1"); return false; }
    //$('.box-ates-ben').load("data/boss/servAbnAtesCab.php?idben="+idnClient+"&atestado=novo&dta="+nwdtInicat+"&dtb="+nwdtTerat);

    //----- Início: Calcula datas da Semana
    var dateStart = data_inicial; //new Date(nwdtInicat+" 00:00:00");
    var dateEnd = data_final; //new Date(nwdtTerat+" 00:00:00");
    var dateRange = rangeDate(dateStart, dateEnd);
    var weeks = "1,3|2,3,4";
    var week = weeks.split('|');

    var codstur = "e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434|c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4";
    var codtur = codstur.split('|');


    //alert(weeks);

    for (var i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
      var wekg = String(week[i].split(','));
      var codturg = String(codtur[i].split(','));
      var dias = String(results[i].split(','));
      const dateFiltered = filterDateByDays(dateRange, wekg);

      //const dateFiltered = filterDateByDays(dateRange, wekg);

      valDates = dateFiltered.map(value => value.toLocaleDateString("pt-br").split('/').reverse().join('-'));

      var arrayall = String(codturg + '_' + valDates + '|' + dias);
      //var arraydta = Array(codw[0]+'_'+valDates);
      //var arraydtb = arraydta.split(',');

      //alert(valDates);
      execVal(arrayall);
      //console.log(arrayall);
      //break;
    }

    function filterDateByDays(range, days) {
      if (!Array.isArray(days)) {
        days = wekg;
      }
      return range.filter(value => days.includes(value.getDay()));
    }

    function rangeDate(dateStart, dateEnd) {
      var dates = [];

      while (dateStart < dateEnd) {
        dates.push(new Date(dateStart.getTime()));
        dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + 1);
      }
      return dates;
    }
    //----- Final: Calcula datas da Semana
/*
    //----- Início: Pegar CODTUR
    var valores = "<?php echo $array_results; ?>";
    var resCod = valores.split('|');
    var cods = String(resCod);
    var codt = cods.split('_');

    for (var i = 0; i < codt.length; i++) {
      var codg = codt[i].split('_');
      var codh = String(codg);
      var codi = codh.substring(codh.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
      var caracteres = codi.length;
      //if (caracteres > 10) { console.log(codi); }
    }
    //----- Início: Pegar CODTUR
*/

    function execVal(arrayall) {
      var diasa = arrayall.split('|');
      var diasb = diasa[1];
      var dias = diasb.split(',');

      var diasx = String(diasb.split(','));


      var cods = arrayall.split('_');
      var codtur = cods[0];

      var codta = diasa[0];
      var codtb = codta.split('_');
      var codtc = codtb[1];
      var datasa = String(codtc.split(','));
      var datas = codtc.split(',');

      //var datasb = String(codtc.split(','));
      //var datasx = datasb.split(',');

      //var o = datas.map(Object);
      //var o = Object.parse(datas);
      //typeof(editableObj.datas);
      //var nwdatas = new Object(datas);
      //console.log(datas);

      for (var i = 0; i < cods.length; i++) {
        //var dias = results[i].split(',');
        //var codturg = String(codtur[i].split(','));
        //var caracteres = datas.length;
        //var arr = dias.some(dias => datas.includes(dias));
        var arr  = dias.filter(dias => datas.includes(dias))

        var b = String(dias);
        var c = String(datas);
        var a = b.indexOf(parseInt(c));

        //var arr = datas.indexOf(angular(results[i]);
        //if (datas.includes(datas) in results[i]) {
        //var verif = (dias.indexOf(datas) != -1);
        //if (verif === true) {
        //if (datas.length in dias === true) {

        //if (arr == true) {
        if (arr.length > 0) {
          //console.log(codtur + " | " + datas.length + " | " + c);
          console.log(codtur+" | "+arr.length+" | "+String(arr));
          //Alert(codtur+" | "+datas.length+" | "+c);
          //alert(datas.length);
          //if (caracteres > 10) { }
          break;
        } else {
          //if (arr == false) {
          console.log(codtur + " | Não");
          //Alert(codtur+" | Não");
          //console.log('Não');
          //alert(datas);
          break;
        }

      }
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<?php
$all_weeks = "1,3|2,3,4";
$array_codtur = "e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434|c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4";
$array_results_dias = "2020-01-15,2020-01-20,2020-01-22,2020-01-27,2020-01-29,2020-02-03,2020-02-05,2020-02-10,2020-02-12,2020-02-17,2020-02-19,2020-02-24,2020-02-26,2020-03-02,2020-03-04,2020-03-09,2020-03-11,2020-03-16,2020-03-18,2020-03-23,2020-03-25,2020-03-30,2020-04-01,2020-04-06,2020-04-08,2020-04-13,2020-04-15,2020-04-20|2020-04-02,2020-04-07,2020-04-08,2020-04-09,2020-04-14,2020-04-15,2020-04-16,2020-04-21";
?>

  Entre com uma data inicial e final:
  <br><br>
  <label>Data inicial
<input type='text' name='dtinicat' value="01/04/2020" id='dtinicat'placeholder='00/00/0000' maxlength='16' style='width:120px;'>
</label>
  <label>Data final
<input type='text' name='dtterat' value="02/04/2020" id='dtterat'placeholder='00/00/0000' maxlength='16' style='width:120px;'>
</label>
  <br><br>
  <input type='button' value='Executar' onclick='calcDayAtes();' style='width:80px;height:30px'>
  <br><br> OBS: As datas vão ser comparadas com os dias da semana. "1,3|2,3,4"
```

Comment: se não montar um exemplo funcionando com todo o código não tem como ajudar. Por exemplo, no pedaço de código que colocou tem a variável `arr`, de onde ela vem? Não dá pra enternder assim.. já fez um debug e tentou perceber o que tem de errado?

Comment: Corrigido @RicardoPontual - Código completo e bagunçado, pois ainda tô mexendo muito e não deu tempo de limpar: [https://jsfiddle.net/brendowsilas/a3vq79mb/30/]

Comment: No "Exibir trecho de código" está funcionando... coloquem a data lá "procês" verem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
var allcods = 
"e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434|c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4";
var cods = allcods.split('|');

var alldias = "2020-01-15,2020-01-20,2020-01-22,2020-01-27,2020-01-29,2020-02- 
03,2020-02-05,2020-02-10,2020-02-12,2020-02-17,2020-02-19,2020-02-24,2020-02- 
26,2020-03-02,2020-03-04,2020-03-09,2020-03-11,2020-03-16,2020-03-18,2020-03- 
23,2020-03-25,2020-03-30,2020-04-01,2020-04-06,2020-04-08,2020-04-13,2020-04- 
15,2020-04-20|2020-04-02,2020-04-07,2020-04-08,2020-04-09,2020-04-14,2020-04- 
15,2020-04-16,2020-04-21";
var dias = alldias.split('|');

var alldatas =  "2020-04-01,2020-04-02"
var datas = alldatas.split(',');

executar();

function executar() {
    for(var i=0;i< cods.length;i++){
        var diasCod = dias[i].split(',')
        var cod = cods[i]

        var filtro  = diasCod.filter(dias => datas.includes(dias))

        if (filtro.length > 0) {
            console.log(cod+" | "+filtro.length+" | "+String(filtro));
        } else { 
           console.log(cod+" | Não");
        }
    }    
}
```

Como resposta da execução desse programa terá:

```
e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434 | 1 | 2020-04-01
c7aead0f41f90cf4eace601998bd78c4 | 1 | 2020-04-02
```

Esse programa pega os dias do código respectivo:

```
var diasCod = dias[i].split(',')
```

pois dias[0] tem todos os dias do primeiro código "e5f6abb0c4b74c20a92195375bef2434" e o mesmo ocorre com o outro código

depois pega o código em questão:

```
var cod = cods[i]
```

Então filtra os dias daquele código pegando todos os dias dentro de "diasCod" que existem na lista "datas":

```
var filter = diasCod.filter(dias => datas.includes(dias))
```

Caso tenha alguem na lista "filtro" imprima na tela quem os elementos dessa lista e de qual codigo são:

```
if (filtro.length > 0) {
    console.log(cod+" | "+filtro.length+" | "+String(filtro));
}
```

Caso não imprima que o código não tem essas datas:

```
else { 
    console.log(cod+" | Não");
}
```

Se ficou com alguma dúvida poderia dar uma revisada nos comandos:

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Pois pelo programa que você postou me parece que você tem uma certa dúvida de como o split funciona.

Espero te ajudado !

Comment: Matou a pau amigo @LucasRamos... era isso aqui: `var filtro  = diasCod.filter(dias => datas.includes(dias))` `if (filtro.length > 0)` Que Deus lhe abençoe... muitíssimo obrigado... valeu mesmo cara... me salvou viu!

Comment: Amigo @LucasRamos, coloquei estas duas partes lá no "Exibir trecho de código" pra vc ver... Abraço! Deus te ilumine

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :) tudo de bom !!